# Why do OG Vocabulary terms not list content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, organic-groups

Drupal 7.41, OG 2.7, og_vocab 1.2.

I've created a group, and a group content type. I added a og vocab to the group and enabled it for the content type. The og_vocab field shows on the node edit page, and the terms in the og_vocab are displayed on the node view. But when I click a term to view all content that has been tagged with that term, the term page does not list any content.

It looks something like:

```
# Term
Primary tabs
View(active tab)    Edit

There is currently no content classified with this term.
```

If I do the same thing with a **normal** vocabulary, the term page **does** list the content.

I've tried just the `taxonomy/term/<term id>` path, as well as the alias pathauto generated `<og vocab name>/<term name>`. Both show the same thing.

As far as I can tell, the only modules that could be overriding the path are views and page manager. I made sure neither was doing so.

So, how do I get the term page for og_vocab terms to list the associated content?

Answer (score 0):

I waited a few days on this to see if anyone posted a solution but no luck..

I've never had any luck with og_vocab and instead use a content type as a group type and use that just like taxonomy. This is possible by using entity reference fields that use entity reference views for values instead of a taxonomy field. But the "taxonomy term" ie. Field value must be set before hand as far as I can tell.

If this solution, and I actually like it a lot, sounds like it could work, I can write up a more detailed guide.